# ManyToMany field returns None instead of giving me the data

Tags: django, django-models

I am developing a restaurant management application in django. When I am trying to print the ordered items of a customer I am getting

```
testapp.Menu.None testapp.Menu.None
```

Only that many to many fiedls is showing none. Other are working fine.

These are my models:

```
categories=(
    ('Starters','Starters'),
    ('Maincourse','Maincourse'),
    ('Breakfast','Breakfast'),
    ('Desserts','Desserts'),
    ('Beverages','Beverages')
)
class Menu(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,choices=categories)
    price=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.IntegerField()
    address=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Orders(models.Model):
    status=(
        ('Out of delivery','Out of delivery'),
        ('Pending','Pending'),
        ('Order recieved','Order recieved'),
    )
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    items=models.ManyToManyField(Menu)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=status)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
```

This is my view.py file

```
def customer_info(request,pk):
    customer=Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    order=customer.orders_set.all()
    
    context={
        'customer':customer,
        'order':order

    }
    return render(request,'customer_info.html',context)
```

My html file

```
<table>
        <tr>
            {{customer.name}}
            <br>
            {% for order in order %}
            {{ order.items }}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: `{{ order.items.all }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% for order in order %}` will not work correctly.

Change your view:

```
def customer_info(request,pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.orders_set.all()
    
    context={
        'customer': customer,
        'orders': orders
    }
    return render(request,'customer_info.html',context)
```

And your template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: {{customer.name}}</td>
        <td>
            Orders:
            {% for order in orders %}
                {{ order.items.all }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you so much. I am getting the query set now. Any idea how to loop through it and print them. <QuerySet [<Menu: lime soda>, <Menu: Baby chicken>]> <QuerySet [<Menu: parotta>, <Menu: falooda>]>

Comment: In your template: `for menu in order.items.all`...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your are a life saviour. Thanks again

Comment: Now you'll probably want to have a look at `select_related` to optimize that orders query...